# How to pass url with query string as an api parameter?

Tags: c#, api, model-view-controller, querystringparameter

I am curently integrating the api to my application. One of the parameter is content_url which is a valid HTML URL for content. How to I pass whole url with query string?

API Endpoint parameter is located below.

```
            var contentUrl
            = "https://www.finnet.com.tr/CMS/OSMANLIMENKULTEST/MailSablon/RaporPaylasimHtml/OSMANLIKP/FXBULTEN/2020-01-20/null";
        var url = "https://campaigns.zoho.com/api/v1.1/createCampaign?" +
                  "resfmt=json&" +
                  "campaignname=Campaign12&" +
                  "from_email=mert.metin@finnet.gen.tr&" +
                  "subject=Test Create Campaign 11&" + 
                  "list_details=%7Bd6ef220cc42b50d7ddf3236cbb9b8847894375f7a7d2d66f%3A%5B%5D%2Cd6ef220cc42b50d71438a8b019c635e5894375f7a7d2d66f%3A%5B%5D%7D&" +
                  "content_url=" + contentUrl;
```

Content url is https://www.finnet.com.tr/CMS/OSMANLIMENKULTEST/MailSablon/RaporPaylasimHtml?SiteKod=OSMANLIKP&Kod=FXBULTEN&Tarih=2020-01-20

But I post url value, API gets the url until first & ampersand character. So remain parameter was missing. I need to pass whole url as a parameter.

Expected Result=https://www.finnet.com.tr/CMS/OSMANLIMENKULTEST/MailSablon/RaporPaylasimHtml?SiteKod=OSMANLIKP&Kod=FXBULTEN&Tarih=2020-01-20

Actual Result=https://www.finnet.com.tr/CMS/OSMANLIMENKULTEST/MailSablon/RaporPaylasimHtml?SiteKod=OSMANLIKP

My application is based on MVC and C# language. I also enclosed the url with double quotes but it is not work because of Api Response which is INVALID IMPORT URL.

Comment: You have to url encode Your `contentUrl`. Other the part behind `&` will be treated as next argument of `url`.

Comment: @ivion  I changed with urlencode but I got 500 error from zoho response. Is it correct encoded url ? and i added `content_url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.finnet.com.tr%2fCMS%2fOSMANLIMENKULTEST%2fMailSablon%2fRaporPaylasimHtml%3fSiteKod%3dOSMANLIKP%26Kod%3dFXBULTEN%26Tarih%3d2020-01-20`   There is an api related error, by information from the api support team.

Answer (score 0):

```
   You must encode the URL before passing as a parameter as

    myURL="myURL1?redir=" + Server.URLEncode("myURL2?id=4&user=test");

    It will create a correct URL without '?' and "&" characters as
  

    myURL= myURL1?redir=myURL2%3id%34%26user%3dtest

    To extract your redirect url from this encoded url you must use     
    HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode to turn it into a correct url again.
```